# JOIN using negation clauses

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got the following table in a Postgres database:

Table **Example**:

```
---------------------------
   name     |    number
---------------------------
DefaultName |       1
DefaultName |       2
DefaultName |       3
DefaultName |       4
Charlie     |       1
Charlie     |       3
Charlie     |       4
Charlie     |       5
Amanda      |       2
Amanda      |       3
Amanda      |       4
Amanda      |       5
```

I need to get the "number"s that are present in the 'DefaultName', but that are not present in each "name"s that differ from 'DefaultName'.
In this case, it would return:

```
---------------------------
   names    |    numbers
---------------------------
Charlie     |       2
Amanda      |       1
```

I am trying a Left Join like the one below, but I can't figure a way to get the DefaultName numbers crossed with a negation with the other names'...

```
SELECT Test_Configs.name, Default_Configs.number

FROM Example AS Test_Configs  
    LEFT JOIN Example AS Default_Configs      
        ON Default_Configs.name = 'DefaultName'
```

Comment: Define "missing". The ones missing between min and max value of a name or overall or some given min / max? Or just the numbers showing up with 'DefaultName'?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the order, or max/min values. It has to do with values that are present in DefaultName, but not in the other names

Comment: I changed my statements, maybe I made myself a little bit clearer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would generate the whole range per name and `LEFT JOIN` to the base table to eliminate the present ones:

```
SELECT n.name, nr.number
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT name
   FROM   example
   WHERE  name <> 'DefaultName'
   ) n                         -- all names except 'DefaultName'
CROSS  JOIN (
   SELECT number               -- assuming distinct numbers for 'DefaultName'
   FROM   example
   WHERE  name = 'DefaultName'
   ) nr                        -- combine with numbers from 'DefaultName'
LEFT   JOIN example x USING (name, number)
WHERE  x.number IS NULL;       -- minus existing ones
```

To list only the gaps for each name individually:

```
SELECT n.name, nr.number
FROM  (
   SELECT name, min(number) AS min_nr, max(number) AS max_nr
   FROM   example
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) n
 , generate_series(n.min_nr, n.max_nr) AS nr(number)
LEFT   JOIN example x USING (name, number)
WHERE  x.number IS NULL;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8aa67/1)

Here are the basic techniques to exclude rows existing in another table (a derived table in this example):

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Comment: I'm not getting those values I intended in the post... I think that maybe the LEFT JOIN statement isn't working well, for the numbers are not coming...

Comment: @ZeldaElf: That's odd, because I do get the result you displayed: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8aa67/1 and `LEFT JOIN` should be working very well, indeed. Are there any `NULL` values involved? Or are all columns defined `NOT NULL`.

Comment: I'm sorry, friend. At Fiddle I saw a mistake about my insertions, pardon me. It worked! But I still can't figure how you did it with the CROSS one. I'll study a bit about it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It will take a few passes, select default, group names that aren't default, then left join and check for null values. Check the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/689d0/1) Example.

```
select Names.name, DefaultConfigs.number
from Example DefaultConfigs
  cross join (
    select name
    from Example
    where name != 'DefaultName'
    group by name
    ) Names
  left join Example Missing on Missing.name = Names.name
    and Missing.number = DefaultConfigs.number
where DefaultConfigs.name = 'DefaultName'
  and Missing.name is null
;
```

Comment: It worked out too, my friend! Thanks for stopping by!

Answer (score 1):

Build all combinations of name and default numbers. Then remove those present.

```
select othernames.name, defaultnumbers.number
from (select number from example where name = 'DefaultName') defaultnumbers
cross join (select distinct name from example where name <> 'DefaultName') othernames
except
select name, number from example;
```